# How to execute nested function from outside

Tags: python

## I want to call b() without making it a global function.

```
def a():
  def b():
    print(0)

a.b()

>> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'b'
```

Is this possible or do i have to make it global?

Comment: Can you make `a` a class, and `b` a method of `a`? That would allow you to call `a.b()`

Comment: There is no `b`. Calling `a` creates `b`. This is the same as any other local variable. If you want its existence to be independent of `a`, it shouldn't be local to `a`.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to have `a` return `b`:

```
def a():
   def b():
       print(0)
   return b

a()()  # prints '0'

b = a()
b()    # also prints '0'
```

In general, you can only access variables that are declared inside a function if they are returned.

This is a pattern you'll see quite frequently in decorator functions, since a decorator typically creates a "wrapper" function locally and then returns the wrapper function as its output.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can have a nested function. Functions are objects and therefore can have attributes.

```
def outer(): 
       print ("outer")
       def inner(): 
           print("inner")
       outer.a = inner  # here .a is an attribute of outer 


outer()
outer.a()
```

It's important that you run outer() before running outer.a() because "outer" needs to define "inner".

Comment: but what if the `a()` contains some operations which make changes to the variables it gets? basically, i am trying to use `timeit.timeit()` for timing a `quick_sort()` (an in-place algo) and all my code is in `main()` - i didn't want to go global for defining one time running setup code which consists of creating a `random_array`, then `copy.copy()` it to `input_array`